# Binding keyword refers to what?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In this example:

```
 <TextBox Name="textBox1" Height="23" Text="some text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,12,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
 <Label Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=textBox1}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

whatever I type on the textbox will be displayed on the label. I am learning xaml and I believe I understand most of the Bindings such as this one. But I think even though I understand what is happening, it will be nice to understand what the Binding keyword refers to? for example I can have:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lv1" />
```

I am having a hard time understanding what binding actually refers to? There is nothing after the Binding keyword, so what is it binding to? Does it refer to that control? Is it similar to the this keyword used in c# where it will refer to the current instantiated object of a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a keyword, it's a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx).

Bindings always bind to the `Path` relative to the source, if there is no path they bind directly to the source, possible sources are the `DataContext` which is used implicitly if no other source is specified and `ElementName`, `Source` and `RelativeSource`. Please read [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) if you have not done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a binding to the Property `DataContext` of the window. If there is a list of elements in 
that, you will see it in the ListBox.

For example type `DataContext = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };` in the constructor of your window after `InitializeComponents();` and you will see that list in your ListBox.

Comment: Yeah I believe I know how it works. I am actually binding it to a linq query. So when there is nothing specified (you just have the {binding} keyword) it refers to the data context of the window? if there is a property specified and a target it will be bind to that target or whatever it is specified?